# How to draw lines and remove after 30 seconds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want, at the end of game, (in Cocos-2D when user makes some mistakes) to draw a X (two crossing lines) from a corner to another corner. After that, when 30 seconds passed, I would like to remove those two two lines.

Here's the code I am using to draw the lines:

```
ccDrawColor4F(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
ccDrawLine(ccp(0,0), ccp(x, y));
ccDrawLine(ccp(0,y), ccp(x, 0));
```

How do I remove those lines after 30 seconds ?

Answer (score 2):

assuming you are using version 3.x ... you could :

```
// figure out maxX and maxY before getting here;
CCDrawNode *dn = [CCDrawNode node];
[dn drawSegmentFrom:ccp(0,0) to:ccp(maxX,maxY) radius:10 color:[CCColor blueColor]];
[dn drawSegmentFrom:ccp(0,maxY) to:ccp(maxX,0) radius:10 color:[CCColor blueColor]];
[self addChild:dn];
id stall = [CCActionDelay actionWithDuration:30];
id clean = [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
    [dn removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}];
id seq = [CCActionSequence actions:stall,clean,nil];
[dn runAction:seq];
```

ob cit: general idea, coded from memory, not tested, not compiled, but gives you a start point.

Answer (score 1):

You can paint those lines to a subclass of a CCNode, and auto-remove this object after 30 seconds.